# HttpPost for Action (save) ends in 404-error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# Website and Web API combined. In the Web API part I have four Controllers (for Products, Categories, Users and Orders). The normal GetAllProducts, GetProduct, etc. that MVC API Controller default use are working fine, but now I want an Action method for a HttpPost (to Save Orders).

Here below is what I had before I wanted to add this Save-Action (PS: At the bottom you can see what I've tried to make the save Action work):

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using System.Web.Security;

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Only allow JSON response format
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        // Default API HttpRoute
        // Call examples: "/api/products" or "/api/products/2"
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Configure the DependencyResolver and register all API-Controllers
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IProductsRepository, ProductsRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ICategoriesRepository, CategoriesRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IOrdersRepository, OrdersRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IUsersRepository, UsersRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        config.DependencyResolver = new ControllerDependencyFactory(container);

        // Some other stuff
        ...
    }
}
```

ControllerDependencyFactory.cs:

```
// This class uses the Inversion of Control (IoC) pattern, which creates
// instances of objects for you. All Web API Objects (API Controllers) are
// registered with this IDependencyResolver, so with a GET-request to the API
// this class will automatically create the correct instance of that API Controller.
public class ControllerDependencyFactory : IDependencyResolver
{
    protected IUnityContainer container;

    public ControllerDependencyFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

        this.container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            // WARNING: Do not throw any errors, we need to return null here
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            // WARNING: Do not throw any errors, we need to return an empty List here
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
        return new ControllerDependencyFactory(child);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

IProductsRepository.cs:

```
public interface IProductsRepository
{
    IEnumerable<ProductsAPI> GetAll();
    ProductsAPI Get(int id);
    // No need for an Add, Update or Remove
}
```

ProductsRepository.cs:

```
public class ProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
{
    private List<ProductsAPI> products;
    private ProductController controller;

    public ProductsRepository()
    {
        // Get the Controller-instance from the RouteMaps instead of creating a new instance here
        getControllerInstance();
        products = controller.ListAll();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ProductsAPI> GetAll()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public ProductsAPI Get(int id)
    {
        return products.Find(p => p.ProductId == id);
    }

    // No need for an Add, Update or Remove

    private void getControllerInstance()
    {
        var url = "~/product";
        // Original path is stored and will be rewritten in the end
        var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        string originalPath = httpContext.Request.Path;

        try
        {
            // Fake a request to the supplied URL into the routing system
            httpContext.RewritePath(url);
            RouteData urlRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

            // If the route data was not found (e.g url leads to another site) then authorization is denied.
            // If you want to have a navigation to a different site, don't use AuthorizationMenu
            if (urlRouteData != null)
            {
                string controllerName = urlRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

                // Get an instance of the controller that would handle this route
                var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, urlRouteData);
                var controllerFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
                var controllerbase = (ControllerBase)controllerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
                controller = (ProductController)controllerbase;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Reset our request path.
            httpContext.RewritePath(originalPath);
        }
    }
```

ProductsController.cs (only used by the Web API):

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private IProductsRepository repository;

    public ProductsController()
    {
        repository = new ProductsRepository();
    }

    // GET /api/products
    public IEnumerable<ProductsAPI> GetAllProducts()
    {
        if(LockAPI.loggedIn)
            return repository.GetAll();

        return null;
    }

    // GET /api/products/5
    public ProductsAPI GetProduct(int id)
    {
        if (LockAPI.loggedIn)
        {
            ProductsAPI item = repository.Get(id);
            if (item == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            return item;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

ProductController.cs (also used by the Website):

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IMyDatabase db;

    public ProductController()
    {
        this.db = new MyDatabase();
    }

    // Some methods used by the Website part
    ...

    // List all products
    // This method is only used for the Web API part of this project, that will be used in the Mobile App
    // Return: actual List of Products, instead of JSON format
    public List<ProductsAPI> ListAll()
    {
        List<ProductsAPI> products = db.Products
            .Where(p => p.Visible == true)
            .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
            .Select(p => new ProductsAPI()
            {
                ProductId = p.ProductId,
                Name = p.Name,
                Price = p.Price,
                CategoryId = p.CategoryId,
            })
            .ToList();

        return products;
    }
}
```

ProductsAPI.cs:

```
public class ProductsAPI
{
    // The Products Fields we use in the Mobile App
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

---

So that's what I had, and I've added/changed the following:

In WebApiConfig.cs changed:

```
// Default API HttpRoute
// Call examples: "/api/products" or "/api/products/2"
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers
);
```

to:

```
// Default API HttpRoute
// Call example: "/api/orders"
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
// API HttpRoute with ID
// Call example: "api/orders/2"
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiWithID",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers
);
// Api HttpRoute with Action
// Call example: "api/orders/save"
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiWithAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

In the OrdersController.cs (only used by the Web API) added the following method:

```
// POST /api/orders/save
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("save")]
public Boolean SaveOrder([FromUri] string UniqueID, [FromBody] dynamic Data)
{
    if(LockAPI.loggedIn)
    {
        // Convert JSON body to a Key-Value Dictionary
        Dictionary<string, object> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(Convert.ToString(Data));

        // Convert data-objects
        ...

        // Use this converted data to save the Orders
        // and return true or false based on the result
        ...
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now I'm using the FireFox RESTClient:

Method: `POST - http://localhost/api/orders/save`

Body: `"productIds": "[20, 25]",     "prices": "[0.40, 7.40]",     dateInTicks: "1402444800"`

And get the following response:

```
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 212
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 08:45:10 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

{
    "$id": "1",
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/api/orders/save'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Orders' that matches the request."
}
```

How to get an HttpPost to a C# mvc Web API to work with Actions?

Comment: the signature of Save method is not matching as per the parameters you are supplying. Try creating dummy Save function taking 0 and 1 paramters and see which one is getting hit by this URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first tried another MapHttpRoute again:

```
// Default API HttpRoute
// Call examples: "/api/products/all" or "/api/products/one/2" or "/api/orders/save" or "/api/test/enable"
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and a small change to the Web API Controllers:

- Added `[ActionName("all")]` to the GetAll-methods (this changes `/api/products` to `/api/products/all`)
- Added `[ActionName("one")]` to the Get-methods (this changes `/api/products/2` to `/api/products/one/2`)

and changed the SaveOrder-method in the OrdersController to:

```
public Boolean SaveOrder([FromBody] string productIds, [FromBody] string newPrices, [FromBody] string dateInTicks)
{
    ...
}
```

When I did the same post with FireFox' RESTClient again, I had a 500-error:

```
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 226
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 14:33:51 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

{
    "$id": "1",
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Can't bind multiple parameters ('productIds' and 'dateInTicks') to the request's content.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": null
}
```

This made a lot more sense.

Then I changed the Save-method to:

```
public Boolean SaveOrder([FromBody] JObject jsonData)
{
    // TODO: Seperate the JSON Data

    // Rest the same as before
    ...
}
```

And now it goes to the method and I can debug through it.

Right now I still have problems converting the JSON in the body to the actual separated data, but that's something for a different question.